# Ruby: Calling gem subclass within module produces uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, module

I have 2 projects, a "common code" project that i have made into a big module that pulls in other modules like so:

Here is the folder structure of "my-common-project":

- **my-common-project**

  - **common**

    - rest-client.rb
    - other ruby files with modules...
  - common.rb
  - Gemfile
  - etc...

## common.rb

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
require_relative './common/rest_client.rb'
...

module Common
  include RestClient
  # include other modules here...
```

## rest-client.rb

```
module Common
  module RestClient

  def call_rest_service_get(url)
    begin
      response = RestClient.get(url, {accept: :json})
    rescue RestClient::Exception => err
      return err.response
    else
      return response
    end
  end
end
```

## Gemfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rest-client'
# other gems here...
```

Then in another project called "my-other-project":

- **my-other-project**

  - **service**

    - service.rb

## service.rb

```
require_relative './../../../common/common.rb'

class Service

  include Common

  def get_rest_data
    call_rest_service_get('http://some-url.com)
  end
end
```

I get an Error when the code makes it to the rescue block in rest-client.rb:

```
NameError - uninitialized constant Common::RestClient::Exception
```

I'm not sure how to phrase my question, but somewhere along the line it seems the common module is losing out on the rest client modules other classes, in this example Exception. Can someone explain why this method of lumping and then including many modules isn't working?

Comment: "I'm not sure how to phrase my question..." Indeed! Glad I found your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a class called `Common::RestClient` and are using a ruby gem which defines a class `RestClient`, when you're within your `Common` module, you'll need to reference the gems `RestClient` with a `::` prefix, otherwise, it assumes you're talking about `Common::RestClient`

```
module Common
  module RestClient

  def call_rest_service_get(url)
    begin
      response = ::RestClient.get(url, {accept: :json})
    rescue ::RestClient::Exception => err
      return err.response
    else
      return response
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed...and a hard thing to search for!